# Is it possible to import "Assigned to" data for Activities?

Tags: activities, import

In the "Import Activities" interface in CiviCRM (version 4.6.3, drupal 7), there are many options for fields to import.  One critical field that appears to be missing is the "Assigned to" field (sometimes referred to as the "assignee").  I'd like to know if it's possible to import this field when importing activities.

This matter was discussed 2 years ago, in this forum thread:

http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=29394.0

> Definition of "Assigned to" from the user guide: "The person (usually within your organisation) that will carry out (or has carried out) the activity."

I'm wondering if any progress has been made on this since that forum thread.

Comment: A small correction: the "assignee" and "target" fields are not the same thing. Target is labelled "With Contact" on the activity edit form.

Comment: Thank you, davejenx.  Your explanation helped to clarify one of the comments in the linked forum thread.  I've edited the original question to omit reference to "target".

Answer (score 3):

I've used this CiviCRM Extension for just that purpose, however, it looks like it's only be released up to 4.4

Might be worth checking if there is a 4.6 version that's not been released

https://civicrm.org/extensions/api-csv-import-gui